# $ is not defined Jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, jquery-ui, web

```
<html>
    <head>
        <script src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.4/jquery.min.js"></script>
        <script type="text/javascript" src="deployJava.js"></script>
        <script type="text/javascript" src="example.js"></script>
    </head>
...
```

I'm trying to solve the problem `$ is not defined`, in example.js in line `$(document).ready(function () {`.

why this not working?

Thanks.

Comment: Can you show your example.js file?

Comment: can product it on fiddle ?? if you do , please provide the link of the fiddle

Comment: I have something like this:
$(document).ready(function () {

But in the before that line, $ don't gives error.

Comment: Looks like in `deployJava.js`, `$` jQuery reference is removed, maybe using jQuery `noConflict()` method. Same issue using `jQuery` not `$` in `example.js`? You could wrap it with: `jQuery(document).ready(function($){...});`

Comment: @A.Wolff I try this but not works :S `$ is not defined` too.

Comment: @PRVS BUT is `jQuery` vriable defined or not in `example.js`???  Is your jQuery link using CDN at least correctly included? Error in network console tab? What if you remove `deployJava.js` include? Etc.. You have to debug it on your side. Regarding your posted code, we cannot really help you more

Comment: The other things give me the same error. But how can I define JQuery variable in example.js?

Comment: @PRVS Maybe this is what is used in `deployJava.js`, [jQuery noConflict()](https://api.jquery.com/jquery.noconflict/). I will stop guessing because you still didn't provide any sample to replicate your issue nor really answer any previously asked questions...  And `But how can I define JQuery variable in example.js` doesn't really make sense. jQuery should already be defined if you didn't override it in some ways, which of course, still regarding your posted code, we cannot be aware of

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Please move the example.js declaration above the deployJava.js.
I think deployJava.js has some script errors.
Thanks.